# How do i evaluate this :$\sum_{k=1}^{+\infty}\frac{{(-1)^k}}{\sqrt{k+1}+\sqrt{k}}$?

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence, summation

I have tried to evaluate the bellow sum using some standard altern sum but i don't succed  then my question here is :

> > Question:
> >     How do i evaluate this sum

$\sum_{k=1}^{+\infty}\frac{{(-1)^k}}{\sqrt{k+1}+\sqrt{k}}$ ?

Note: Wolfram alpha show it's values [here](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=sum_%7Bk%3D1%7D%5E%7B%2B%5Cinfty%7D%7B%7B(-1)%5Ek%7D%7D%2F%7B%5Csqrt%7Bk%2B1%7D%2B%5Csqrt%7Bk%7D%7D)

Comment: It doesn't converge. $\sum_{k=1}^{+\infty}\frac{{(-1)^k}}{\sqrt{k+1}+\sqrt{k}}$ does.

Comment: sorry i meant + in denominator

Comment: That's better. But it's elementary that it converges, because it's an alternating series, and $\frac1{\sqrt{k+1}+\sqrt{k}}$ is monotone decreasing. Calculating the sum is another business. =D

Comment: Since
$$\frac{1}{\sqrt{k}+\sqrt{k+1}}=\sqrt{k+1}-\sqrt{k} = \int_{0}^{+\infty} \left(\frac{1-e^{-s}}{2s^{3/2}\sqrt{\pi}}\right)e^{-kx}\,dx \tag{A}$$
we have:
$$ \sum_{k\geq 1}\frac{(-1)^k}{\sqrt{k}+\sqrt{k+1}} = -\frac{1}{2\sqrt{\pi}}\int_{0}^{+\infty}\frac{1-e^{-s}}{s^{3/2}(e^s+1)}\,ds \tag{B}$$
and the series in the LHS is clearly convergent by Leibniz' test.

Comment: The RHS of (B) gives a relation between the values of the $\zeta$ function at half-integers and the LHS.

Comment: BTW, the sum can be expressed by a single value of the $\zeta$ function: it's $-2\,(2\sqrt{2}-1)\,\zeta(-1/2)-1$.

Answer (score 1):

Since
$\frac1{\sqrt{k}+\sqrt{k+1}}
=\sqrt{k+1}-\sqrt{k}
$,
the sum of consecutive
odd and even terms is

$\begin{array}\\
-\frac{1}{\sqrt{2k}+\sqrt{2k-1}}+\frac{1}{\sqrt{2k+1}+\sqrt{2k}}
&=-(\sqrt{2k}-\sqrt{2k-1})+(\sqrt{2k+1}-\sqrt{2k})\\
&=\sqrt{2k+1}-2\sqrt{2k}+\sqrt{2k-1}\\
&=\sqrt{2k}(\sqrt{1+(1/2k)}-2+\sqrt{1-1/(2k)})\\
&=\sqrt{2k}(1+\frac1{4k}-\frac1{32k^2}+O(1/k^3)-2+1-\frac1{4k}-\frac1{32k^2}+O(1/k^3))\\
&=\sqrt{2k}(-\frac1{16k^2}+O(1/k^3))\\
&=-\dfrac{\sqrt{2}}{16k^{3/2}}(1+O(1/k))\\
\end{array}
$

Taking more terms
in the expansion of
$\sqrt{1+x}$
would give
expressions involving
$\frac1{k^{m+1/2}}$
for $m=2. 3. ...$.

Summing these involves
$\zeta(m+1/2)$.